# How to calculate $q_{1}(t)$, $q_{2}(t)$, $p_{1}(t)$, $p_{2}(t)$ using Euler's method?

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

From my understanding, this assignment wants me to calculate $q_{1}(t)$, $q_{2}(t)$, $p_{1}(t)$, $p_{2}(t)$ using Euler's method. I am a quite confused as to how to proceed.

For example, at $t_{0}$, $q_{1}(t)$ is $1-e$.

What about at $t_{1}$? 
$$q_{1}(0.0005) = (1-e) + 0.0005(0)$$
$$q_{2}(0.0005) = (0) + 0.0005(\sqrt{\frac{1+e}{1-e}})$$
$$p_{1}(0.0005) = (0) + 0.0005(\frac{-1}{((1-e)^2 + 0^2)^{3/2}})(1-e)$$
$$p_{2}(0.0005) = (\sqrt{\frac{1+e}{1-e}}) + 0.0005(\frac{-1}{((1-e)^2 + 0^2)^{3/2}})(0)$$

Are they correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this first step is correct. However, you will need to write some code, like for instance in [this answer about Euler and RK4 in orbital mechanics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645649/cannot-get-rk4-to-solve-for-position-of-orbiting-body-in-python/53650879#53650879), it would take far too much paper to do the $400,000$ steps manually.